# What statistical test should I use and for what reason?

Tags: multiple-regression, likert

My dependent variable is an index from annual reports of companies (ranging from 0 to 1). The independent variables will be measured with Likert scales (individuals in each company will respond to the questions – a group of items rated with a Likert scale). What is the most appropriate statistic to use in this scenario? I need help please.

Dependent variable (index from one company) $=f$(Three separate Likert Scales measuring three different issues)

Comment: Why is the index bounded between 0 and 1, in terms of the data-generating process?

Comment: Yes, how do you get numbers between 0 and 1 from a Likert which is most often 5 points?

Comment: @DoctorAmbient The (0,1) variable is the DV (the $y$), while the Likert scales are the IVs (the $x$'s).

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry!  Totally misread that!  Does the index have an interpretation as a probability or as something else?  The suggestions below deal with the transformation of $y$, but should the $x$'s be transformed, too?  Are they all the same Likert scale, or do the scales vary?  (I've seen that happen more than you think!)

Answer (score 1):

Transform the dependent variable by taking ln(y/(1-y)) in a way as with the logistic regression and regress that on the predictors. After that check the residuals for normality.

Answer (score 0):

Papke and Wooldridge ([J. Appl. Econometrics, 1996](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-1255%28199611%2911:6%3C619%3a%3aAID-JAE418%3E3.0.CO;2-1/abstract)) suggest a so-called fractional logit model, a GLM with a binomial distribution and a logit link function, since the traditional tobit regression is non-applicable when outcomes outside of [0,1] are unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a much more simple model. try first to fit a simple linear model. Your likert variables can be coded as dummy variables.